# Error during clusplot in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

While performing clustering using R I have come across an error. I have a dataset *d* which is a distance matrix. Variable *fit* is obtained by the following

```
fit <- kmeans(d,k=2) # assume that number of cluster lie between 1 and nrow(x)
clusplot(d, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade = TRUE, lines=0)
```

The error that is being displayed is

> Error in mkCheckX(x, diss) : x is not a data matrix

The matrix d is given by

```
structure(c(2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2), Size = 4L, Diag = FALSE, Upper = FALSE,
          method = "euclidean", call = dist(x = DATA, method = "euclidean"),
          class = "dist")
```

Comment: can you provide the matrix d?

Comment: use dput(d) and paste the result, you can modify your answer to include that.

Comment: structure(c(2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2), Size = 4L, Diag = FALSE, Upper = FALSE, method = "euclidean", call = dist(x = DATA, 
    method = "euclidean"), class = "dist")

Thanks a lot

Comment: try using directly DATA instead of d = dist(DATA).

Comment: I got the result. But why was using dist(DATA) causing problem? 
The resultant distance matrix is also a matrix. So why the error?

I was learning from the following link: 
[This Link](http://www.slideshare.net/ChiuYW/machine-learning-using-r)

Comment: The explanation in the answer, tell me if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clusplot` function accept its first argument to be a matrix or data frame, or a dissimilarity matrix (or a distance matrix), depending on the value of the `diss` argument, which is `FALSE` by default. See `?clusplot` for more information.

So, you need to use:

```
d = dist(DATA) # for a distance matrix or d = daisy(DATA) for a dissimilarity matrix
clusplot(d, diss=TRUE, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade = TRUE, lines=0)
```

or

```
clusplot(DATA, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade = TRUE, lines=0)
```

You get the error because your matrix `d` is not being recognized as a matrix by the function `mkCheckX`, since for R is an object of class `dist` (not a matrix!). If you try `is.matrix(d)` you should get `FALSE`.

Also, not expect to have the same results using both methods, since when providing the data matrix the clustering is produced in a different way (basic on principal component descomposition, looking to the code).

If you check the help for `dist`, you can see you can use different methods ("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski") to calculate the distance, and you should expect different clusterings by changing the way to calculate the distance.

In summary, you distance matrix is not a matrix for R, so you got the error you saw.

Comment: The two above mentioned codes produce different results. How can they be equivalent? And _d_ is not a dissimilarity matrix in the given question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also can you tell me where can I get more information about cluster analysis using R?